# Get past row limitation

Tags: crystal-reports

My report processes millions of records. When the number of rows gets too high, I get this error:

> The number of rows or columns is too big. Try limiting the number of unique group values.
>   Details: The number of rows or columns exceeds its limit, 65535.

How can I work around (or increase) this limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is pretty straightforward. 65535 is 0xFFFF in hexadecimal, so once you hit that limit there's no more vacancies and the hotel is closed. Solutions include:

1. Reduce the number of rows displayed by using grouping in your crosstab or whatever.
2. Reduce the amount of incoming data to your report with Record Selection. (Parameters)
3. Perform the dependent calculations in a custom SQL statement, generated as a temporary table in your report. You can then pass the results into your report as fields, rather than having to print millions of lines.